# `glmRob()` does not predict when given `newdata` argument

Tags: r, glm, robust

The following is some slightly modified code from the `glmRob()` examples. When given the `newdata` argument, `predict.glmRob()` errors out. Am I doing something wrong?

```
suppressMessages(library(robust))
data(breslow.dat)
bres.rob <- glmRob(sumY ~ Age10 + Base4 * Trt, family = poisson(), data = breslow.dat)
predict(bres.rob, newdata = breslow.dat)
```

> Error in NextMethod("predict"): no method to invoke

```
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#>  os       macOS Catalina 10.15.7      
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/Los_Angeles         
#>  date     2020-12-14                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  callr         3.5.1   2020-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  cli           2.2.0   2020-11-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  DEoptimR      1.0-8   2016-11-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  devtools      2.3.2   2020-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  digest        0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  fit.models  * 0.64    2020-08-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  knitr         1.30    2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  lattice       0.20-41 2020-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  MASS          7.3-53  2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  mvtnorm       1.1-1   2020-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  pcaPP         1.9-73  2018-01-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  processx      3.4.5   2020-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ps            1.5.0   2020-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  R6            2.5.0   2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rlang         0.4.9   2020-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.5     2020-10-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  robust      * 0.5-0.0 2020-03-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  robustbase    0.93-6  2020-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  rprojroot     2.0.2   2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rrcov         1.5-5   2020-08-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  testthat      3.0.0   2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  usethis       1.6.3   2020-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  withr         2.3.0   2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  xfun          0.19    2020-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#> 
#> [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Worth noting that the exact same thing does work with regular `glm()`.

```r
suppressMessages(library(robust))
data(breslow.dat)
bres.glm <- glm(sumY ~ Age10 + Base4 * Trt, family = poisson(), data = breslow.dat)
predict(bres.glm, newdata = breslow.dat)
#>        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#> 2.957756 2.933407 2.704879 3.015431 3.913226 3.250763 2.979112 4.101214 
#>        9       10       11       12       13       14       15       16 
#> 3.360129 2.863352 3.955120 3.257157 2.912460 3.741554 4.459110 3.668917 
#>       17       18       19       20       21       22       23       24 
#> 3.034205 5.093412 3.131601 2.906475 2.930414 2.671553 3.110244 3.174723 
#>       25       26       27       28       29       30       31       32 
#> 3.873096 3.134184 2.644211 3.507451 3.917288 3.375050 2.641300 2.675629 
#>       33       34       35       36       37       38       39       40 
#> 2.592602 2.854897 3.163672 2.890335 2.625822 3.756825 3.201280 2.557211 
#>       41       42       43       44       45       46       47       48 
#> 2.784067 2.988840 3.585320 3.060731 3.448097 2.484164 3.182476 2.577124 
#>       49       50       51       52       53       54       55       56 
#> 5.757692 3.003209 3.274328 3.308657 3.525533 3.268830 2.863768 2.857114 
#>       57       58       59 
#> 2.805090 2.891444 2.892553
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Just take out the `newdata` argument since you're running it on the same data.

From the robust docs [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robust/robust.pdf)

*newdata* - optionally, a data frame in which to look for variables with which to predict. If omitted, the fitted linear predictors are used.

**Edited to add**

One of the listed authors replied and recommended using the package "robustbase" (whom he's the maintainer of) as opposed to "robust" because the methods used in the former are more modern, as well as backed by more extensive testing and examples.

Here's my sample code for a quick comparison between the two. Note that the 'r' in robustbase's glmrob is lowercase.

```
library(robustbase)
library(robust)
data(breslow.dat)

## Comparison of methods.

bres.robustbase <- glmrob(sumY ~ Age10 + Base4 * Trt, family = poisson, data = breslow.dat)
predict(bres.robustbase, newdata = breslow.dat)

bres.robust <- glmRob(sumY ~ Age10 + Base4 * Trt, family = poisson(), data = breslow.dat)
predict(bres.robust)

## predict handling test data on robustbase's glmrob object.

lastIndex = round(nrow(breslow.dat)*0.7)
train = breslow.dat[1:lastIndex,]
test = breslow.dat[(lastIndex + 1):nrow(breslow.dat),]

bres.robustbase <- glmrob(sumY ~ Age10 + Base4 * Trt, family = poisson, data = train)
predict(bres.robustbase, newdata = test)
```

Notice that you'll get different coefficient estimates, and therefore predictions, between `glmrob` and `glmRob`. Deciding which one's more accurate is beyond my knowledge at the moment (hopefully not for you), but I've followed up with our author to see if he can give a high-level explanation that can be posted here.

Comment: this is interesting but might not actually solve the OP's problem. (I spent a little while digging around in S3 method dispatch etc. etc. but didn't manage to get very far ...)

Comment: Yes, it looks like the NextMethod is not getting passed through properly & perhaps  `family(object)$inverse` should be `family(object)$linkinv`. I think a bug should be raised with `maintainer("robust")`

Comment: If OP's question pertains to why can't he pass a dataframe through `newdata` period, I agree (worth reaching out to the package authors). It looks, however, that he was just trying to replicate the example given by runnig `predict` on the *same entire set* of the data, which makes using the `newdata` argument unnecessary.

Comment: So just to clarify. I want in general to use the `newdata` argument to predict on fresh data. Here I just passed the fitting data into `newdata` to show that the model wasn't even able to predict on its own data (to clarify that whatever issue there was was nothing to do with the format of the data I was passing).

Comment: Copy. Thanks for the clarification. I'll reach out to the package authors.

Comment: @Econundrums ; thanks for following up. Re the coefficients, on my pc the coefficients are unstable under `glmRob` i.e. they  change wildly on different runs , and hence can get some wild predictions.

Comment: @user20650 I guess all the more reason to use robustbase then ;)